# Excluir datos de un campo SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

como se podría hacer una consulta pero mostrar todo menos dependiendo de un dato de un campo en SQL Server, por ejemplo tengo un tabla de comida con 2 campos:
**campo 1:** 'S' comida buena, 'A' comida regular y 'D' comida mala.
**campo 2:** Nombre de varias comidas(caseras, fastfood, internacional, etc).
Y quiero mostrar todo menos donde haya **'D'** en el **campo 1**

Comment: Hola, Jose. Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar tu consulta y añadir qué consulta SELECT has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, nos ayudaría mucho una consulta SQL de partida para conocer el nombre exacto de la tabla y del campo. En caso contrario tendríamos que adivinar cuales son.

Comment: Que, por cierto, dependiendo del campo o del uso que le quieras dar la solución podría ser un `NOT LIKE`, un `<>` (que es lo mismo que un `!=`) o un `NOT IN (...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los [operadores de comparación (ver documentación)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) son algo muy básico en SQL:

- `<>` (No es igual a)
- `!=` (No es igual a)

También podrías usar [`NOT LIKE` (ver documentación)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) si quieres usar patrones de cadenas o bien [`NOT IN (...)` (ver documentación)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) si quieres excluir un conjunto de coincidencias.

Ejemplos:

- `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE campo != 'D'`
- `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE campo <> 'D'`
- `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE campo NOT LIKE 'D'`
- `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE campo NOT IN ('D')`

Tienes un ejemplo en línea en la siguiente URL:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a39YzjezQCWaz6ZAjDP2Aq/0